# Electric potential of conductive ball

Tags: charge, potential

Why is the electric potential inside and on the casing of a conducive ball is the same?

And why can I approach a conductive charged ball as a dot of charge in space (like all the charge is concerned in its middle) when I look at it from outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two questions here. You should ask them separately.

The electrostatic potential on a conductor's surface is teh same, **if it is in equilibrium**. Equilibrium implies charges cannot accelerate, so they must neccesarily have no electric field parallell to the surface. $E=0 \Leftrightarrow V=const.$

And the second solution is found integrating. If you do the math, you'll see that the result is the same as the one of a point charge in the centre. You can see it as "symmetry causes contributions of opposite sides to cancel out"; and you have only a radial component.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the electric potential inside and on the casing of a conducive
>   ball is the same?

The electric potential inside a conductive ball is the same as the potential on the outside surface of the ball, because there is not field inside the ball. Since there is no field, the potential does not change as we move from the surface inwards, i.e., it remains the same everywhere inside the ball.

> And why can I approach a conductive charged ball as a dot of charge in
>   space (like all the charge is concerned in its middle) when I look at
>   it from outside of it?

This could be shown by a direct application of the Gauss's law and the observation that the electrical field around a spherical conductor should be symmetric. Nicely explained [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesph.html).